# What tree is this(maybe wild tobbaco)?

Tags: identification, trees

A friend using a tree identification app, said it could be a wild tobacco tree. We don't know who planted it, and is not a common tree in our place. My location is Cyprus (island in eastern Mediterranean). I would like to know more about.

ps.chair for scale
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wild tobacco  tree refers to Solanum mauritianum and the leaves on your plant are entirely dissimilar. What are the flowers like and do the fruits I can see forming turn red or black or another colour?

Comment: I am not sure, if it flowers or not. The fruits are turning yellow and then black. I added another picture with the fruits.

Comment: Just a quick response, haven't looked further yet,but if its got fruits, it must have flowered, cos that's where fruits come from.

Comment: I'll ask about it , and be back at you then for info about the flowers.

Comment: Well, don't worry about what the flowers look like too much - if it flowered and you didn't notice, they might be small and insignificant anyway. What might be helpful is if you could pick one of the fruits, cut it in half and see what's inside... a pic of that might help.

Comment: @Bamboo uploaded a pic with the fruits (knife for scale :-) )

Comment: The fruits look like Wild Tobacco.  The leaves look like Mulberry.  This is another interesting ID!